# R script to check if my zip folder is corrupt

Tags: r

There is a python testzip() module to check if a zip file is corrupt in python. However i want to know it's parallel in R as well.

How to check if a zip folder is corrupt by writing a small script in R ?

Comment: can u provide a corrept zip file?

Comment: no actually i don't have one unfortunately just want to test it on a normal folder